# Postgresql CASE WHEN to extract max and min date

Tags: postgresql

Here's the problem occurred.

[image]

What I trying to do was add status to the table according to their starting time.

However, all the status turned out to be 'shortest serving' which is pretty weird.

Can somebody explain it and fix the problem?

Comment: SELECT 
CASE
    WHEN starting = max(starting) THEN 'shoretst serving'
    WHEN starting = min(starting) THEN 'longest serving'
    END AS status,
    name,faculty,starting
    FROM q2derived
    GROUP BY name,faculty,starting

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: I guess "which is pretty weird" is your (unproductive) way of saying "which is the correct result, but unexpected, so I made a mistake and/or have a misconception"?

Answer (score 1):

Use window functions:

```
CASE
   WHEN starting = max(starting) OVER ()
   THEN 'shortest serving'
   WHEN starting = min(starting) OVER ()
   THEN 'longest serving'
END
```